# How do i add tables inside of a function in Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to do:
`function objects:add(namespace, x, y, w, h, mode, density, r)`
then make a new table. `objects.namespace = {}`
then return the table by: 
`return objects.namespace`
but i want the 'namespace' to **actually** be defined in the function... how would I go about doing that?
and when i try to call something inside the table I.E: `print(objects.newBox.x)`
it gives me 'NIL'

Even if I try:

```
function test(name)
  print(name)
  [name] = {"yo"}
end
test(doit)
```

It gives me an error: 'attempt to index a nil value'
I must be doing something wrong...

```
table = {}
function table:add(name, x, y)
  table.[name] = {}
  table.[name].x = x
  table.[name].y = y

  return table.[name]
end
table:add(box1, 300, 100)
print("table.box1.x: " ..table.box1.x)
print("table.box1.y: " ..table.box1.y)

-- [name] is to be defined in the function arg.
-- then i want to return the table and use it's contents for other uses I.E line 10 and 11
-- gets the following error: '<name>' expected near '['
```

Comment: `objects[namespace] = {}`

Comment: Whenever I try ` objects[namespace] = {}
 objects[namespace].x = x` i get the error: 'table index is nil' on the line of 'objects[namespace] = {}'

Comment: How are you calling `objects:add`?

Comment: Insert this as the first statement in the function to get an error in a better place with a better message: `assert(namespace and namespace == namespace,'namespace cannot be nil or NaN')`, or, if you mean this, `assert(string.find(namespace,'^[_%a][_%w]*$'),'namespace must be an identifier')`.

Comment: To answer @lhf, the line after the function ends, i call `objects:add(testBox, 100, 20, 32, 32, "dynamic", 1, 0.4)`

Comment: `namespace` is not supposed to be a string, but an identifier defined in the function.

Comment: Also, to reply to @TomBlodget, That kinda doesn't really help my situation.... (To tell me that there is an error when I already know that..) (I'm not trying to be rude)

Comment: Please try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard (for me at least) to know what you are trying to do without it.

Comment: Here is the [MCVE] (https://gist.github.com/MTadder/6d8a155ad58f3462e5e0) on Github Gist.       @rpattiso

Comment: Parameter validation is a situational best practice. In this case, it would have been a useful "divide and conquer" stategy for the debugging problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```
t = {}
function t:add(name, x, y)
  t[name] = {} -- or use  t[name] = {x=x, y=y} and remove the  next 2 lines
  t[name].x = x
  t[name].y = y
  return t[name] -- necessary?
end

t:add('box1', 300, 100)

print("t.box1.x: " ..t.box1.x)
print("t.box1.y: " ..t.box1.y)
```

- Naming a variable `table` will hide the table library so I have changed it to `t`
- When you call `t:add(box1, 300, 100)` box1 is not defined so it's value is `nil`, which isn't a valid key for a table
- you want to use `"box1"` as the key since `t.box1` is just sugar for `t["box1"]`
- In your function `t:add` you want to index `t` with the value of name, the syntax is `t[name]`
- You also aren't using the return value and you can get to it from `t` with `t.box1`. it seems unnecessary
- using `:` suggests you want to implement objects? If that is the case, see [PIL Object Oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) for an introduction on how to implement that

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for helpful feedback and tips :D AWESOME!!